# is there is any way to select sum(columns) and list other columns in Mysql php?

Tags: mysql

i mean for examle    : [     select *,sum(column) from tablename   ]

```
 select *,sum(price) from parcels
```

the output was : one row as full table contents and last column of total amount .

what i want is to get the list of all rows with total amount in the last column is that something doable or can be done?

websoor.com

Comment: Try with `GROUP BY`  in your query.

Comment: Don't simply use GROUP BY with your query. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sometimes using two queries to achieve two different objectives is the best way to go.

Comment: Why not generate the sum column with your code, rather by mysql.

Comment: because i want to filter it by date which my be different everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `SUM` is an aggregate function (i.e. returns one row for each `GROUP`). When `GROUP BY` is omitted the `GROUP` is effectively the entire table.

You could do this with a sub `SELECT` statement as one of the columns which returns the `SUM`:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(price) FROM parcels) as sumTotal FROM parcels
```

However, you're probably better off simply running the two queries separately?

**Note**

It's generally better to avoid using `*`. Rather you should specify the field names - that way if the DB design changes (e.g. a new column added after `id`) and you've used numerical column indexes in your code then your code won't be affected.

Comment: this is just what i needed , because in php html i can mention rows and put it where ever i want .thanks man !